# How to redirect to pre-defined error page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, asp.net-4.0

I have error page settings in my web.config like:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="ErrorDocs/500.htm">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorDocs/404.htm"/>
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorDocs/403.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

Is there a simple way to redirect to 404 page without typing its name? Ex: Response.Redirect(404 status coded page);
Or is there a way to get default 404 location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you *can* certainly get the settings out of your web.config file programmatically if you want - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup.aspx - rough code:

```
    string my404Setting;

    // Get the application configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup sectionGroup in config.SectionGroups)
    {
        if (sectionGroup.type == "customErrors" )
        {
            foreach (ConfigurationSections section in sectionGroup.Sections)
            {
               if (section.StatusCode = "404")
               {
                  my404Setting = section.Redirect;
                  break;
               }
            }
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Uglier than it should be, but that's how you'd read what you want.

Comment: Although I've implemented another way to handle errors this is the nearest answer.

Answer (score 1):

From answer here:  [Best way to implement a 404 in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667053/best-way-to-implement-a-404-in-asp-net)

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){
  // An error has occured on a .Net page.
  var serverError = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

  if (null != serverError){
    int errorCode = serverError.GetHttpCode();

    if (404 == errorCode){
      Server.ClearError();
      Server.Transfer("/Errors/404.htm");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately those paths only work with static page paths.