# creating a 404 page not found error in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been finding a code in C# asp.net for a 404 error how do I create a 404  error that works significantly everytime whenever a page does not exist?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems doesn't fit here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Please read how to ask question first

Comment: Do you means something in UI or backend ?. The only thing you need to care is result the response with code 404. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667053/best-way-to-implement-a-404-in-asp-net

Comment: can you just tell me a code or something please?

Comment: like I created a page Contact.aspx and if somebody by mistake opens Contactme.aspx  I want to generate a 404 error page how can I do that any code?

Comment: Hussam Hussien thank you but it's still giving me an error

Comment: @AliMoosa Sorry, this is not a site to get your homework done. We dont just provide you with some code solution. Ask a good question, then you might get a good answer.

Comment: Sorry it's just that I'm new to programming :'|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your custome 404.aspx page and you  have to put this in your web config before the final configuration tag

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>

    <customErrors defaultRedirect="404.aspx" mode="On" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

that's all :)

Comment: it's giving me an error on mode="DetailedLocalOnly"

Comment: so try to put mode="On"

Comment: and also try  mode="RemoteOnly"
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>

Comment: You are welcome Eng.Ali Moosa