# Return 404 status code in aspnet core SPA Angular application

Tags: angular, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am working on a project using the Angular SPA project template for dotnet core (the one available in VS2017 and dotnet core 2.0).

I have an Angular component to display a "Not Found" message if a user goes to an invalid URL.

I also have server-side pre-rendering enabled. When returning the prerendered "Not Found" page from the server, how would I make it return an HTTP status code of 404?

Every method I have found to do this uses Express as the backend webserver, I have not been able to find any resources for doing this on an aspnet core backend.

Thanks for any help!

---

Edit for clarity:

I am not looking to return a 404 for a specific MVC controller action or on an application error.

I am looking to return a 404 from a specific Angular2/4 component, rendered server-side by [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices).

For comparison, [here](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/667#issuecomment-318547053) is an example of a solution using the Express web server on NodeJS and angular universal for server-side rendering.

Comment: i think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667053/best-way-to-implement-a-404-in-asp-net

Comment: better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690114/asp-net-core-how-to-return-a-specific-status-code-and-no-contents-from-control

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but neither of these addresses my issue. They are both talking about returning 404 responses from a standard ASP.Net/ASPNet Core application and not a server-side rendered Angular component. I edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution.

First, we need to create an injectable service that components can use to set the status code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HttpStatusCodeService {

  private statusCode: number;

  constructor(){
    this.statusCode = 200;
  }

  public setStatusCode(statusCode: number) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }

  public getStatusCode(): number {
    return this.statusCode;
  }
}
```

We will need to add this service to the `providers` array in the main `AppModule` module:

```
...
providers: [
    ...
    HttpStatusCodeService,
    ...
]
...
```

And then we need to add two lines (plus the import statement) within our `boot.server.ts` file (note this is based on the stock file created by the VS2017 template):

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode, ApplicationRef, NgZone, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { platformDynamicServer, PlatformState, INITIAL_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { createServerRenderer, RenderResult } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.server';

//ADD THIS LINE
import { HttpStatusCodeService } from './path/to/services/http-status-code.service';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const providers = [
        { provide: INITIAL_CONFIG, useValue: { document: '<app></app>', url: params.url } },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
    ];

    return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
        const appRef: ApplicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
        const zone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);

        //ADD THIS LINE: this will get the instance of the HttpStatusCodeService created for this request.
        const statusCodeService = moduleRef.injector.get(HttpStatusCodeService); 

        return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
            appRef.isStable.first(isStable => isStable).subscribe(() => {
                // Because 'onStable' fires before 'onError', we have to delay slightly before
                // completing the request in case there's an error to report
                setImmediate(() => {
                    resolve({
                        html: state.renderToString(),

                        //ADD THIS LINE: this will get the currently set status code and return it along with the prerendered html string
                        statusCode: statusCodeService.getStatusCode() 
                    });
                    moduleRef.destroy();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And then finally we need to set the status code in any component that shouldn't return HTTP 200:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpStatusCodeService } from './path/to/services/http-status-code.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'not-found',
    templateUrl: './not-found.html'
})
export class NotFoundComponent {

  constructor(private httpStatusCodeService: HttpStatusCodeService) {
    httpStatusCodeService.setStatusCode(404);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please also guide how to handle this in new Angular CLI based template for .net https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1288#issuecomment-346003334 . I think angular part would be mostly same but I am unable to figure out the .net portion.

Comment: There is no .NET portion, the answer above is all Angular. It looks like the Angular CLI based template changes a lot, including how the Angular application is built and bootstrapped. Skimming through the docs referenced in the template's `Startup.cs` file (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501), it looks like you need to add a `main.server.ts` file that is similar to the `boot.server.ts` in the RTM template, however it is different enough that I have no idea how to handle this within it, nor do I have the time to try and figure it out right now.

Comment: Entith can you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50937983/2755616 and share your feedback on this approach for new Angular CLI Based template?