# ASP.Net Core 2.1 Angular SSR/Universal returning Http Status Code 404

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular6, angular-universal, asp.net-core-2.1

With `SpaPrerenderingExtensions` available in ASP.Net core 2.0 `JavaScriptServices`, it seems that we can return the HTTP Status Code from the Angular (SSR) App which `SpaPrerenderingExtensions` will use to return the HTTP Status Code to the client.

If you take a look at below method in `SpaPrerenderingExtensions`

```
private static async Task ServePrerenderResult(HttpContext context, RenderToStringResult renderResult)
```

Complete code of `SpaPrerenderingExtensions` is available here: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/8ded472fe93123079ab97c9332f24460340876d2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs

You will notice that `renderResult.Html` contains the html markup returned from Angular Server App whereas `renderResult.StatusCode.Value` contains the status code.

The official documentation for enabling SSR (available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#server-side-rendering) suggest adding below code to the `main.server.ts` file.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

  const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl }
    ]
  };

  const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return renderPromise.then(html => ({ html }));
});
```

Can anyone please guide how do I return the status code from the Angular Server App so that its properly picked up by the `ASP.Net Core 2.0 SpaPrerenderingExtensions`.

Any help would be highly appreciated. For example if I have a service which has value of status code, how do I pick value from that service and pass to server in `main.server.ts` file.

Note: I am using ASP.Net Core 2.1 Angular CLI 6 based template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried below approach and it seems to work, any feedback and improvements would be highly welcomed. I am not sure if this approach is thread safe. What I mean is if concurrent requests are served by the server, is it possible that the status code of one request is assigned to other request since this approach is taking benefit of the fact that the sub properties of `constant` objects are mutable.

**I created a file `globals.ts` with below code:**

```
export const response = { statusCode: 200 };
```

**Then, I created a service StatusCodeService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as myGlobals from './globals';

@Injectable()
export class StatusCodeService {

  setStatusCode(statusCode: number) {
    myGlobals.response.statusCode = statusCode;
  }

}
```

Now whenever I have to set the status code, I use this service to set status code.

**I have also updated the `main.server.ts` file with below code to pass value to the server:**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.module.server';

import * as myGlobals from './app/globals';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;
  const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl }
    ]
  };

  const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return renderPromise.then((html) => {

    let statusCode: number = 200;
    if (myGlobals.response.statusCode == 404) {
      statusCode = 404;
      //reset status code to 200 for next request
      myGlobals.response.statusCode = 200;
    }

    return {
      html: statusCode == 404 ? 'Page not found!' : html, StatusCode: statusCode
    }

  });
});
```

**I also tried the approach mentioned in [Return 404 status code in aspnet core SPA Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777364/return-404-status-code-in-aspnet-core-spa-angular-application/46790709#46790709)**

I updated the main.server.ts file for Angular 6.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { enableProdMode, ApplicationRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { platformDynamicServer, PlatformState, INITIAL_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { createServerRenderer, RenderResult } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
import { AppServerModule } from './app/app.module.server';

import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

//ADD THIS LINE
import { HttpStatusCodeService } from './path/to/services/http-status-code.service';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {

  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

  const providers = [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
    { provide: INITIAL_CONFIG, useValue: { document: '<app-root></app-root>', url: params.url } },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
  ];

  return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppServerModule).then(moduleRef => {
    const appRef: ApplicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
    const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
    const zone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);

    //ADD THIS LINE: this will get the instance of the HttpStatusCodeService created for this request.
    //const statusCodeService = moduleRef.injector.get(HttpStatusCodeService);

    return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
      zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
      appRef.isStable.pipe(first(isStable => isStable)).subscribe(() => {
        // Because 'onStable' fires before 'onError', we have to delay slightly before
        // completing the request in case there's an error to report
        setImmediate(() => {
          resolve({
            html: state.renderToString()//,

            //ADD THIS LINE: this will get the currently set status code and return it along with the prerendered html string
            statusCode: statusCodeService.getStatusCode()
          });
          moduleRef.destroy();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But when I run the app, its almost broken and have below issues:

- There isn't any style sheet in the generated markup.  Server Transfer
  State is missing.  fxFlex layout doesn't work.

Comment: Does the `const` in your `globals.ts` maintain its state across multiple requests? If you remove the `myGlobals.response.statusCode = 200;` reset, do all requests after the first 404 also return a 404? If so, then your solution is certainly not thread safe. Is there no way to get a service instance from the dependency injection system like I did in my solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790709/1257979)?

Comment: Thank you Entith for the feedback, yes you are right if I remove 'myGlobals.response.statusCode = 200;' reset, all requests after the first 404 also return a 404. From my component, when I update the value of 'myGlobals.response.statusCode = 400;'', I stop all processing in that component and return immediately. I also tried your approach in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790709/1257979, but the generated markup seems to have these issues: The server transfer state doesn't seem to work. fxLayout seems broken and its missing the stylesheet.

Comment: I did not mean to copy my `boot.server.ts` like that, it looks like they changed the bootstrap process too much for that to work. Take a look at this: https://pastebin.com/D71VNV2k  You would have to figure out how to access the dependency injector to get the `StatusCodeService` instance.

Comment: Yes that's the main point with that approach, I don't think with new approach there is any way to access dependency injector. Since renderModuleFactory returns Promise<string>.

Comment: I added an answer, see if you're able to get it working with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer because I can format things better than in a comment, however this is all untested and based of looking at my outdated solution, your code snippets above, and the Angular6 docs (I don't have the latest VS templates so I can't test at the moment).

The `options` parameter object that is given to both [renderModule()](https://angular.io/api/platform-server/renderModule) and [renderModuleFactory()](https://angular.io/api/platform-server/renderModuleFactory) has an `extraProviders` array that, I believe, will let us add additional providers to the `AppServerModule` module.

Here is my idea:

- Use my `HttpStatusCodeService` from my answer here: [Return 404 status code in aspnet core SPA Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777364/return-404-status-code-in-aspnet-core-spa-angular-application/46790709#46790709)
- Add it to the `providers` array in the `AppBrowserModule` module (only the browser module, not the server module).

  - This will allow the service to be injected normally while the app is running in the browser.
- Instantiate `HttpStatusCodeService` in `main.server.ts` file and add that instance as a provider in the `extraProviders` array.

  - This will allow the service to be injected while the app is running on the server while also giving us a reference to the injected service.
- Use the reference to the service to determine if the response needs to be a 404.

Here is my **untested** attempt to modify your `main.server.ts` file snippet to work.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.module.server';

//ADD THIS LINE
import { HttpStatusCodeService } from './path/to/services/http-status-code.service';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

  //ADD THIS LINE - We manually instantiate the service so we have a reference to it.
  let statusCodeService = new HttpStatusCodeService();

  const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },

      //ADD THIS LINE - We add a provider for the service that uses our instance. 
      { provide: HttpStatusCodeService, useValue: statusCodeService },
    ]
  };

  const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return renderPromise.then((html) => {

    //ADD THIS LINE - get the status code from the service.
    let statusCode: number = statusCodeService.getStatusCode();

    return {
      html: statusCode == 404 ? 'Page not found!' : html, StatusCode: statusCode
    }

  });
});
```

In my original solution, I rendered my 404 Not Found page using an Angular component, so I wouldn't override the returned HTML (`html: html, statusCode: statusCode`).

And for the sake of completeness, here is the `HttpStatusCodeService` from the answer linked to above:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HttpStatusCodeService {

  private statusCode: number;

  constructor(){
    this.statusCode = 200;
  }

  public setStatusCode(statusCode: number) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }

  public getStatusCode(): number {
    return this.statusCode;
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works. If it doesn't, I can try to get a test environment set up to poke at this some more, but no promises.

Comment: I am unsure of the scoping of the `let statusCodeService = new HttpStatusCodeService();` line. My assumption is that we'll get a new instance for each page that is rendered, however that might not be the case. You will want to test going to an invalid URL followed by a valid URL and make sure the valid URL returns a 200 after the 404 from the invalid one.

Comment: I seem to be getting a different instance of statusCodeService :(