# Angular 6 Access Dependency Injector in renderModuleFactory

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular6, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Can anyone please guide how to access the **dependency injector** to get the a **service** instance in renderModuleFactory?

Actually I need this in main.server file to return proper http status code for SSR. With ASP.net we don't have access to Response object as we have it available in case of NodeJs.

Please also take a look at [ASP.Net Core 2.1 Angular SSR/Universal returning Http Status Code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50934948/2755616) to understand the context.

Comment: Please help me out for angular 9 404 status code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code

Answer (score 0):

I just now solved this by doing the following. This question is almost a year old, but maybe this is still helpful.

```js
export { AppServerModule } from './server/app-server.module';

// Add this line so that you can provide this token in your aspnet-rendering script as shown below.
// The reason we have to export the service here is so you can get access to the same copy used by the Angular code.
export { StatusCodeService as StatusCodeServiceToken } from './server/services/http-response.service';
```

```js
const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, StatusCodeServiceToken } = require('./../server/main.js');

export default createServerRenderer(async params => {
  // Instantiate your service manually.
  const statusCodeService = new StatusCodeService();

  const options = {
    document,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      // Provide your instance as a value provider.
      { provide: StatusCodeServiceToken, useValue: statusCodeService }
    ]
  };

  const html = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? await renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : await renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return {
    html,
    // Then you can retrieve the value because you have the instance.
    statusCode: statusCodeService.statusCode
  }
});
```

Comment: Please help me out for angular 9 404 status code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code